# How to make a Timelion geo query (example)?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I'm trying to run a Timelion command that needs to include a geo filter query. 
What would be the correct syntax to do that? Please include an example if possible.

So far, I have tried using the following JSON geo query directly, but that doesn't work.

```
 "geo_distance" : {"distance" : "12km","pin.location" : {"lat" : 40,"lon" : -70}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geo queries are not possible in Timelion, as the only "query" you can use is the `.es(q=..)` which uses `query_string` that has no support for geospatial queries.